# How to connect to Odoo Data with JDBC api via Talend?

Tags: api, jdbc, odoo, talend, data-integration

I wanted to extract data from an odoo database on a cloud environment, I tried this jdbc url : **jdbc:odoo:User=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;URL=http://MyOdooSite/;Database=MyDatabase;**

But I didn't got any results. Do you have any idea, please?

Comment: Hi, JDBC is a database client and Odoo is an application server. There is a jdbc addon for odoo but I am not sure if you are using this one https://www.cdata.com/drivers/odoo/jdbc/ . Odoo uses postgres as a database so you can try the following: `jdbc:postgresql://postgresserverip/odoodatabase?user=odoousername&password=odoopassword` - https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! Yeah I tried that jdbc :
I set the Url to the Odoo site, User and Password and Database to the Odoo database. I added the JAR file "Odoo JDBC Driver" but this only works in localhost! Whenever I tried to connect to a cloud odoo database, It fails. 
Okay I'm gonna try with postgresql. Thank u so much!